# Use an Arch Linux installation pendrive as live one

Tags: linux, usb-flash-drive, arch-linux

I have my Arch Linux installation pen drive and I'm wondering if I have to install it on other disk or flash drive. Can I use this installation pen as there was a system and install X11 and all packages I want there?

Answer (score 0):

No. What you have is (most likely) an installation disk, not a live system with persistence (which seems to be what you want).  For some instructions on how to set up a live system with persistence, see the [Arch Linux wiki here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key).  However, that page says it's out of date, and doesn't point one to up to date instructions.  I am a Debian Live user myself (as a live system with persistence on a pen drive) so I don't have more details.  Incidentally, if you are not committed to Arch, the Debian Live system is the most reliable, consistent and flexible that I've found for running Linux off of a pen drive.